# Почему не работает запрос(sql server)?

Tags: sql-server

Привет. Есть такая таблица -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Сотрудники] (
[Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Имя]           NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Фамилия]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Отчество]      NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Дата рождения] DATE           NOT NULL,
[Должность]     INT            NOT NULL,
[Отдел]         INT            NOT NULL,
[Кабинет]       INT            NOT NULL,
[Город]         NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Адрес]         NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Телефон]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

И такой запрос -

```
SELECT * FROM [Сотрудники] WHERE Фамилия = 'Варнавский'
```

При выполнении запроса нет никаких результатов, и ошибок нет. Запись с такой фамилией существует. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А так: `... WHERE Фамилия = N'Варнавский'`?

Comment: @Yaant спасибо! Так работает. Что это за N?

Comment: N говорит серверу о том, что это строка в юникоде. Без нее у вас где-то происходит неявная конвертация кодировки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**N** перед строковой константой означает, что сервер будет воспринимает это значение в формате **Unicode**.

Это значит что:

- каждый символ занимает 2 байта
- code page **НЕ** используется для вычисления такой константы
- константа имеет `default collation` текущей базы (если не задан другой `collation`), т.е. на нее распространяюся правила сравнения (*comparison rules*) и чувствительность к регистру символов (*case sensitivity*) collation-а